# Import of an unknown module in Python

Tags: python, node.js

[An example of what I need on Node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqJvQ.png)

How can you import an unknown module into Python?
I need to be able to check the existence of a module and import it if it exists, or send a message that the module is not found.

I hope for your help >-<

Comment: Show code properly formatted in the question, not as image or external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
try:
   import {Package-to-import}
except ModuleNotFoundError:
   {Do something if import fails}
```

If you want some context from the exception you can use the following for the except statement

```
except ModuleNotFoundError as exc:
```

`exc` will be the instance of the raised exception.

Answer (score -1):

for example:

```
lib = 'sqlite3'
exec(f'import {lib}')
print(sqlite3.connect)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32214409)